# Using arrayUnion causes memory leak

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to upload an array of state to an array in Firestore however it is yealding in a warning "cant perform update on an unmounted state." and when I go to the database I can see that the data has not been stored.

```
const dbh = firebase.firestore();
        this.state.players.map(player => {
        if(player.Present === true){
            this.setState({
                enrolledPlayersList: [...this.state.enrolledPlayersList, player.id]
            })
        }
    })
    const finalList = this.state.enrolledPlayersList
    dbh.collection("Groups").doc(this.state.group)
    .collection('Enrolled').doc('ids').update({
         players: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(finalList)
    })
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code? This warning is related to your use and update of the `this.state`. Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3038), it may be useful for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by placing my connection to the database in a componentDidMount() function as follows

```
componentDidMount(){
const dbh = firebase.firestore();
    this.state.players.map(player => {
    if(player.Present === true){
        this.setState({
            enrolledPlayersList: [...this.state.enrolledPlayersList, player.id]
        })
    }
})
}
```